# ; how can i put provider to use redux react 18 react native can some please explain to react native 0.69

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-18

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);

```
/**
 * @format
 */

import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

i cant find out how can i pull in it?

Answer (score 0):

In App.js

```
<Provider store={store}>
 ...Your App
</Provider>
```